# help me solve concurrent assignment error in verilog for the code given below?

Tags: verilog

Error is concurrent assignment to a non-net "c" is not permitted.

```
module ha (sum,carry,x,y);
  input x,y;
  output sum,carry;
  assign sum = x^y;
  assign carry = x&y;
endmodule

module vedic_2bit(a,b,clk,rst,c);
  input clk,rst;
  input [1:0] a,b;
  output reg [3:0] c;
  reg [3:0] t;
  always@(posedge clk)
    if(rst)
      begin
        c <= 0;
      end
    else
      begin
        c[0] <= a[0]&b[0];
        t[0] <= a[1]&b[0];
        t[1] <= a[0]&b[1];
        t[2] <= a[1]&b[1];
      end
  ha H1 (c[1],t[3],t[0],t[1]);
  ha H2 (c[2],c[3],t[2],t[3]);
endmodule
```

Comment: Use in-built code editor to format your code in the question

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are driving register c from both modules.

Comment: You defined `c` as a variable type (`reg`). Module puts need to be connected to a net-type (ex `wire`). However a  wire cannot be assigned in a procedural code (ex `always` block). So you need to think how to assign some bits to from a module and other from procedural.

Comment: And avoid this amateurish port-mapping format `ha H1 (, , ,)` which can introduce 'invisible' bugs. Use associative port mapping `ha H1 ( .(something) => something , ......)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the problem is that c[1], c[2] and c[3] are assigned by the rst part of your clocked process, and you're also trying to give them combinatorial assignments by wiring them up to the module below. c[0] is actually fine.